# finding the parameterization of intersection of a sphere and a plane

Tags: vectors, parametrization

**Information given:**  $$x+y+z = 0$$  $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$
We have the portion of the intersection of these two equation going from $(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ to $(0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

**What I need to find:** The parameterization of this intersection.

**Where I'm at:** I know that I need to take the first vector $\vec{a} = (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and find a vector ($\vec{b}$) that is perpendicular to that vector and on the curve of the intersection.

The problem is that I don't seem to quite understand how to do it

After that I would only need to take this equation $\vec{r}(t) = cos(t)\vec{a} + sin(t)\vec{b}$ to find parameterization, because it's a circle.

Comment: You have already written down a possible $\vec b$: $(0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving $$x+y+z=0$$ and $$y-z=0$$

We find that $(-2,1,1)$ is a solution.

Normalize the vector.

$$\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt6}, \frac{1}{\sqrt6},\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\right)$$

is perpendicualr to $a$ and lies on the curve of intersection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm just wondering how you know that solving that was gonna give you a perpendicular vector? And how did you came with y - z =0?

Comment: $\vec{a}$ is in the direction of $(0,1,-1)$, to be perpendicular to it, make sure the dot product is zero.